# window.location seems to cancel ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to send data to php with ajax and at the same time redirect to that php file but when I redirected to the php file, the ajax didn't seem to send the data. I wanted to achieve something wherein a button is clicked and a data is sent to php using ajax and at the same time redirect to that php file to see the data sent by displaying it. The reason I didn't use something like `window.location="ajaxtest.php?data=data"` is because I'm gonna be using it in a google map api wherein if I click a button of a place, then I will redirect to the maps page and display the marker of the specific place depending on the id the ajax sent to the php file and the coordinates generated based on that id.

ajaxtest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").click(function(){
            var data = "test";
            $.post("ajaxtest.php",{
                 data: data
            },function(data, status){
                 window.location="ajaxtest.php";
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<button id="button">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxtest.php

```
<?php  

if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    echo $_POST['data'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Sending data to ajax file and relocating to this file are **TWO DIFFERENT** requests and one knows **NOTHING** about another.

Comment: this wont work because your "opening the same page on two different tabs" the ajax request and the window.location are two different events and has nothing to do with each other

Comment: You can't do this because AJAX requests only live as long as the tab/window is open and on the page that sent them. You can either wait for the AJAX request to finish successfully before redirecting, or send the data via normal form submission.

Comment: What If I'll call more than one function on click? Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, you can call multiple functions onclick, but the "A" in AJAX is for "asynchronous", you can't know when a AJAX request is going to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, that's not how HTTP, AJAX, or PHP work. There isn't any POST data when you do your redirect, because the redirect is a separate request from the AJAX post. What you want is to do an AJAX post and somehow consume the response on your page, without doing a redirect at all.

Comment: I did not downvote but maybe _he/she_ expected to have an example instead?

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, hope you guys have a good day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like ajax is the way to go here. If you want to redirect to a different page just do `window.location.href = 'ajaxtest.php?id='+locationId;` and in your ajaxtest.php:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;

if ( ! $id) {
    die('ID missing');
}

// Show marker 
?>
```